# `gcloud app instances ssh` command disable SSH host key checking

Tags: ssh, gcloud

Let's say I have some command/script that I want to execute on my gcloud app instance:

```
gcloud app instances ssh --quiet \
       --version=${version} --service=${service} ${instance_id} --container=gaeapp -- \
       bash commands.sh
```

How to disable SSH host key checking for `gcloud app instances ssh`? Because currently I have the following result:

```
Executing command in container blah-blah (version=20180813t144010, service=default)
...
Sending public key to instance [apps/blah-blah].
Waiting for operation [apps/blah-blah] to complete...done.                                   
The authenticity of host 'apps/blah-blah (123.123.123.123)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:....
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Answer (score 1):

The workaround for me was to create the ssh fingerprint before running the command:

```
INSTANCE_NAME=$(gcloud app instances list --service="$RUN_SERVICE" --version="$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA" --project="$PROJECT_ID" --format="value(ID)" --limit=1)
INSTANCE_IP=$(gcloud app instances list --service="$RUN_SERVICE" --version="$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA" --project="$PROJECT_ID" --format="value(instance.vmIp)" --limit=1)
ssh-keyscan -t ed25519  "$INSTANCE_IP" | sed "s/$INSTANCE_IP/gae.$PROJECT_ID.$INSTANCE_NAME/g" >> ~/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts
```

I also found another issue that you cannot login using the "root" user, So if the current account you are logged into is root it will try to create a login that is also called root on the target machine which is prohibited by default. So my workaround for that was to wrap this all into a `su some-other-user -c 'bash my_script.sh'`

Answer (score 0):

There isn't currently an option for that, but you could make a feature request at the [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187143&template=0).